# How can I report spam about my Apple ID

Tags: email, security, apple-id, spam

I received a spam email that pretends that I have to validate my Apple ID account information.

> Our automated system was recently unable to validate your details and therefor we require you to complete a short validation process. Please proceed to the link below in order to avoid any interruption to your Apple services.

Where can I report this to Apple?

Comment: This isn't just SPAM. This is a phishing attack you can see if you look at the included link real source. You will notice this link is not pointing to a real Apple web server. It could be something like: `https://security.apple.hosting.com` or `https://security.appl∈.com`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Phishing & Other Suspicious Emails

Apple offer the e-mail address **reportphishing@apple.com** for this purpose:

> ### [Reporting Suspected Phishing Attempts](https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/)
>
> If you receive what you believe to be a phishing email purporting to be from Apple, please send it to **reportphishing@apple.com**, a monitored email inbox, which does not generate individual email replies.
>
> Forwarding the message with complete header information provides Apple with important information. To do this in OS X Mail, select the message and choose Forward As Attachment from the Message menu. For other email applications or webmail based services, consult your provider’s support information to determine how to forward messages with complete headers.